# AS3 Flash - toggle animation on KeyPress

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

When my game character is hitting the computers, and spacebar is pressed the animation changes to `gotoAndStop(2)`. This is working so far.

What i want is so that when i press the spacebar again it goes back to `gotoAndStop(1)`

How would i go about doing this?

Here's my code:

```
public function turnOn(event:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if(jon.hitTestObject(computers) && event.keyCode == 32)
        {
            computers.gotoAndStop(2);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check current frame of computers: `computers.currentFrame`.

Your code will be looks like:

```
if(jon.hitTestObject(computers) && event.keyCode == 32)
{
    if (computers.currentFrame == 1)
        computers.gotoAndStop(2);
    else if (computers.currentFrame == 2)
        computers.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```